# Is there software where I can simulate events on humans?

Tags: simulation, health

*This is a copy of [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/183889/is-there-a-site-where-i-can-simulate-injuries-or-external-events-on-humans), which I now realize is better off on this site*

For a story writing purpose, I'm looking for a (preferably free and no download needed) site that will let me simulate events on humans so I can get an accurate idea on how my characters should react, or at least give me the injuries they would have. Ideally, this software would let me do whatever to the human and I can see the results of it.

*If it requires download or pay, it's not a deal breaker, so put it in an answer or comment anyways.*

Again, Mutilate a Doll doesn't help.

Comment: By "events" do you mean different types of injuries? Or something else too?

Comment: @Alejandro, injuries, but I'd also like to simulate the knife being thrown, the bullet angle, etc, so that i don't risk getting the injuries wrong if i just say 'broken left leg' as opposed to lining up the baseball bat and then applying the appropriate forces.